# NO foreign keys created though I created them . It shown me no error while executing the query. but now showing no foreign keys for my schema

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I executed script related to create  my database ..it executed successfully. but no foreign keys created . I am using cent os . mysql 5.0.

Comment: -1 for "*respond ASAP*". This is not a paid support forum

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just edit the question, that's the proper way. Be nice to new commers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the DB engine is one that does not support FK, it will show you no errors, but won't create them. For example, MyIsam.

Choose InnoDB as the table type to be able to create FK on it.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much...U helped me a lot...I resolved the issue...Thanks a lot.. Now I have some problem in creating trigger.I am pasting my trigger below..it is showing some syntax error.Actually I created in the local system successfully, but getting error while creating at server.

Comment: U should do several things to use this site properly: 1. Mark my answer as the correct one (by pressing the V). 2. Post the trigger question as a separate question 3. It is probably due to u using mysql 5.0 and not a more advanced server. or using the wrong delimiter for the the trigger

Comment: @user1625806 If you have a new question, post it as a separate question. It's more readable that way and more people will be able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

are the tables in MyISAM instead of InnoDB?

MyISAM don't support foreign keys.

Comment: afaik triggers not working right now in MySQL? it's "syntactically implemented" but does not work as far as i know...